# crispy_forms_tag' is not a valid tag library

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to create a Django app using Django crispy-forms.

**settings.py**

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'face',    #app name
    'crispy_forms',
)
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tag %}

{% block title %}
AuthorizedUser
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Quote of the Day</h1>
    <blockquote>{{quote}}</blockquote>
    <p>Or, hit reload if you want a new one...</p>

    <form method="POST" action="{% url  %}"  >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy}}
        <input type="hidden" name="quote" value="{{quote}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="access_token" value="{{access_token}}" />
        <input type="submit" value="Set as my status!"/>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

When I'm running server it's raising an error

> "`TemplateSyntaxError at / 'crispy_forms_tag' is not a valid tag library: Template library crispy_forms_tag not found, trieddjango.templatetags.crispy_forms_tag,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.crispy_forms_tag,django_facebook.templatetags.crispy_forms_tag,crispy_forms.templatetags.crispy_forms_tag`".

What am I doing wrong? And how to fix it?

Comment: Why you dont use django forms? There you should define a helper..

Answer (score 22):

I've gone through that error just now.

Forgot to [install django-crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-django-crispy-forms)

```
pip install django-crispy-forms
```

and refer it in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
]
```

Once that was done, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 6):

You should add Crispy Form tag in project setting .

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
]
```

add these crisp tag in your templates.html

```
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
      {% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form %}
```

Comment: When I got this error I had added `'crispy_forms',` to the `settings.py` but must have forgotten to save and reload. Just a reminder to try that :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the installation of Crispy forms worked ? you need to install django-crispy-forms.

Then, in your template index.html, you should use the crispy tag as following :

```
{% crispy name_form %}
```

instead of :

```
{{form|crispy}}
```

What's more, you should use

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
```

not,

```
{% load crispy_forms_tag %}
```

Comment: what does name_form here mean?

Comment: The name of the form you define. What's more, you should use 
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %} instead of {% load crispy_forms_tag %}

Comment: When I got this error I had added `'crispy_forms',` to the `settings.py` but must have forgotten to save and reload. Just a reminder to try that :)